# Picasso can't load bitmap from Uri - ImageView shows up as a black view

Tags: android, android-camera, picasso

I am using a custom camera and when the user clicks the camera button, it should call this method. The `data` parameter is the image taken in bytes. I expect this method to make a bitmap out of the image, put it in a bundle then put that bundle in a fragment that will display the image. This is called from my `Camera.PictureCallback`.

```
public static void displayCameraImage(byte[] data) {
    BitmapFactory.Options scalingOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    final Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, scalingOptions);
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment displayImageFragment = new DisplayImageFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("image", bmp);
    displayImageFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.flMainContainer, displayImageFragment, "confirmselfie");
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

In the `onCreateView()`method inside the `DisplayImageFragment` I get the bitmap from the bundle and try to load it using Picasso like so:

```
Bitmap bmp = getArguments().getParcelable("image");
final Uri uri = getImageUri(getContext(), bmp);
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(uri).into(ivImage, new ImageLoadedCallback(progressBar) {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                if (this.progressBar != null) {
                    this.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
```

For some reason, this doesn't display the image taken - instead, it displays a black ImageView. Does anyone know why this might be happening? Appreciate any efforts.

EDIT: if anyone's interested, the `getImageUri()` method is here:

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context context, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), inImage, "confirmSelfie", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

I have also tried loading from file (`new File("path")`) instead of directly passing in the Uri.

Comment: What is the `getPath()` and `toString()` values of the Uri?

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo it's something along the lines of "content:///......./media/1894" - can give you an exact path in a few hours when I'm home and can fiddle with the project.

Answer (score 0):

use something like this, If you are unable to load URI then make a file for the URI.

```
File f = new File("path-to-file/file.png")
```

or

```
File f = new File(uri)

Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(f).into(imageView);
```

Comment: I have tried that already (forgot to mention) and had the same issue